# Linking with Boost error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, linker

I just downloaded and ran the boost installer for version 1.42 (from boostpro.com), and set up my project according to the getting started guide. However, when I build the program, I get this linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_program_options-vc90-mt-gd-1_42.lib'
```

The build log adds this (I've replaced project-specific paths with *'s):

```
Creating temporary file "******\Debug\RSP00001252363252.rsp" with contents
[
/OUT:"*********.exe" /INCREMENTAL /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_42_0\lib" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\hw6.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"********\Debug\***.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

".\Debug\****.obj"

".\Debug\****.exe.embed.manifest.res"
]
Creating command line "link.exe @********\Debug\RSP00001252363252.rsp /NOLOGO /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT"
```

I've also emailed info@boostpro.com (with a message very similar to this), but I thought maybe so would be faster.

**EDIT:** Yes, I checked if the file was there before asking this question, and yes, it's path is in the linker properties, under "Additional Library Directories" (I've tried with and without quotes).

**EDIT 2:** And it definitely sees the path because it appears in the 3rd line of the build log...

**EDIT 4:** Nevermind, it doesn't work in release mode or debug mode, but the file that doesn't work changes appropriately (same when I change the runtime library to a different type of multithreaded - I don't see single-threaded as an option, although it would work for me). Trying command line now.

Comment: Well, have you verified the file actually does exist?

Comment: Which libs did you opt to install when prompted by the BoostPro installer?  'mt' means multi-threaded and the 'd' means debug.

Comment: Yes, the file is there. The first time I installed, I think I just did the two single-threaded versions, the second time, I installed every version

Comment: It's in C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_42\lib, and I can open it in Notepad++

Comment: Have you added that path to your project's library path?

Comment: Yes, it's in the linker properties, under "Additional Library Directories"(I've tried with and without quotes).

Comment: Are you able to compile something using that boost library from a VC++ command prompt?

Comment: Just a thought but check in your library dependencies are set for debug mode also. In the file exists and the release mode works, most probably debug mode has troubles with path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a slight difference between the documentation and my actual installation. Where the documentation has "boost_1_42_0" in the path, the installer made my path "boost_1_42". With that fixed, it works.